# AfterViewChecked behaves differently in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: angular, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, lifecycle

I've noticed that AfterViewChecked on Chrome behaves differently than it does to Firefox.

In my case on Chrome runs if there is a change in an Input data, on the other hand on Firefox it keeps executing (infinite till its destroyed), what ever there is in AfterViewChecked regardless if changes happening.

Why is this happening? And how can i manage to have the same behaviour cross-browser ?

```
 ngAfterViewChecked() {
      console.log('test');
     }
```

Comment: Can you add some evidence that what you are seeing in Chrome is different than what you are seeing in Firefox? That function is one of Angular's lifecycle hooks so it runs at a very specific point.